# Is there a pure CSS solution to maintain a square aspect ratio when resizing using the `resize` property?

Tags: css

Is there a pure CSS solution to maintain a square aspect ratio when resizing using the `resize` property?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>Should stay square as you resize</div>
```

<strike>I've tried `resize: horizontal` only and setting explicit height, etc. None of it works. Is there no pure CSS solution here? If there's a solution using some sort of container element, that's fine too.</strike>

Never mind, this tweaked code works fine, as @TemaniAfif correctly pointed out in the comment below. Someone please mark this as solved since there doesn't appear to be an option for me to do it on my own post/question.

Comment: resize: horizontal and set width not height

Comment: @TemaniAfif That doesn't work. I've tried all those combinations.

Comment: it does work: https://jsfiddle.net/xkthnz9c/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Wow, you're right. It does work. The reason it didn't seem like it was working at first is because I had *already* resized it, and the hot module reloading was applying the new css properties but without resetting the dynamic width settings from the resize. Refreshing the page did the trick. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

### Flaw in this solution

You can resize it to a lower width without keeping the aspect ratio.

### Difference between this and `resize: horizontal` solution

This still renders the vertical and horizontal (South-East) resizer, unlike `resize: horizontal`.

This solution has a flaw in comparison to `resize: horizontal`, however, as mentioned above.

---

### Solution

I will try to explain my solution the best I can, but ultimately, I think the best explanation is the DOM hierarchy.

The .wrapper is the element that enforces the square aspect ratio, it's set to flex so that the .container element can be aligned to the *bottom* of the .wrapper.

The .container element is set to start with 100px width as you specified, this can be changed, this is the actual resizable element. With this being aligned to the end, the resizer will always be on the bottom.

The .content element is absolute positioned to overlap the entire .wrapper, putting it at the original position of what .container would have been. This is where the actual content goes.

However, it has to be unclickable, because otherwise it overlays the resizer, therefor, the .content-pointers is where all the content goes, beyond .content.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;

  aspect-ratio: 1;
  
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  pointer-events: none;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-pointers {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-pointers">
        Hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Solution to the width flaw

We can add a resize observer that observes for changes when the width does not equal to the height, which should only happen when the width is decreased in the resize.

This does introduce JavaScript, however, and in such case - I think going for a full JavaScript solution would be somewhat more preferable.

```js
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((events) => {
  for(let index = 0; index < events.length; index++) {
    const event = events[index];
    
    if(event.target.style.width == event.contentRect.height)
      continue;
      
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.style.minWidth = event.contentRect.height + "px";
    }, 0);
  }
});
  
const containers = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

for(let index = 0; index < containers.length; index++) {
  const container = containers[index];
  
  resizeObserver.observe(container);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;

  aspect-ratio: 1;
  
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  pointer-events: none;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-pointers {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-pointers">
        Hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the long response, but Temani Afif's solution above works fine for my purposes (directional resize cursor notwithstanding). It's actually one of the first things I had already attempted prior to posting my question, but quirky hot module reloading led me to believe that the styling wasn't working, when it actually was. Just had to refresh the page. :)